# Kotlin standard function to create if null and return all in one

Tags: kotlin

I need to create a `Thing` if null, otherwise return existing one. Obv I  want to avoid NPEs so no `!!`. Is there a more idiomatic way to write this (maybe better use of `?:` or using one of the standard functions?

```
class Thing {
}

private var myThing: Thing? = null

fun getThing(): Thing {
    // if null create, otherwise return exiting
    val tempThing = myThing ?: Thing()
    myThing = tempThing
    return tempThing
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Thing { }

private var myThing: Thing? = null

fun getThing() = myThing ?: Thing().also { myThing = it }
```

Comment: I should also mention `val myThing by lazy { Thing() }`. If you aren't going to assign null later on to `myThing` and you can initialize it, this might be what you are actually looking for.

Comment: As well as being simpler, `by lazy` is also thread-safe, which a naive implementation isn't.

Comment: Although I didn't share this in my OP `getThing()` takes in an argument to build `Thing`, so I have to stick with your first answer. But your comment answer does answer my question as I posted it.